# Does $f(x) = |x|$ have a local minimum?

Tags: derivatives, graphing-functions

I would like to know whether $f(x) = |x|$ has a local minimum at $x = 0$. 
For a local minimum, the first derivative of the function has to be zero. However, in the case of $|x|$, the function is not differentiable at $x = 0$. Will the point (0,0) still be considered as a local minimum?

Comment: Don't forget that a function can be at a minimum or maximum when the derivative is zero *or undefined.*

Comment: If $x_0$ is a local minimum (or maximum) **and** the function admits derivative at $x_0$, then the derivative is 0 there. But nowhere in the definition of minima (or maxima) the function needs to be differentiable.

Comment: The first derivative test is a tool, not a requirement. It may not be applicable if the function isn't differentiable. You also have to consider endpoints of domain components (intervals), where the derivative can exist and be nonzero (your domain isn't explicitly stated). For example, the function $g:[1,2]\to\mathbb R$ with $g(x)=|x|$ has a local minimum at $x=1$, and $g'(1)=1$.

Comment: sufficient and necessary conditions mixed up..

Comment: @Pieter21: Knowing that $f'(0)=0$ isn't a sufficient condition for $f$ to have a local minimum at $0.$ Rather, *if* $f$ is differentiable at $0,$ then $f'(0)=0$ is, indeed, a necessary condition for $f$ to have a local minimum at $0.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need derivatives here because you have $f(x)=|x|>0$ for every $x \in \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$ and $f(0)=0$ so $0$ is really local and global minimum.

For example, the function $f(x)=\begin{cases} \frac {1}{x^2} &\text{ if } x \neq 0\\0 &\text{ if } x =0.\end{cases}$ has local minimum at $0$ and not only that it is not differentiable at $0$ but it is not continuous at $0$.

Answer (score 4):

You have it the wrong way. A function doesn't have to be differentiable (at a point) to attain a minimum or maximum there. Look up the definition of 'minimum' and 'maximum' in your book or course notes; it is (only) about the neighboring function values.

However: **if** a function is differentiable, then you have a minimum or maximum when the **derivative changes sign** there (*careful*: a zero derivative isn't sufficient; e.g. $f(x)=x^3$).

In your example, $|x|$ attains a local (and even a global) minimum at $x=0$, although the derivative doesn't exist there.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is a local minimum, end even a global minimum, as 
$$\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\, f(x)\geq f(0)$$
The function does not need to be differentiable to have local minimum. What is true is that if it's differentiable and if $x$ is a local minimum, then $f'(x)=0$.

Note that the converse is false. Counter-example: $f(x)=x^3$. We have $f'(0)=0$ but $0$ is not a local minimum.

Answer (score 1):

You have it backwards. If $f'(x_0)= 0$ and $f''(x_0) \gt 0$ then there is a local min at $x = x_0$. Because $f(x) = |x|$ is not differentiable at $x=0$, then the derivative test does not apply there. Still it is pretty clear that if $x \in (-\delta, \delta)$ then $f(0) \le f(x)$. Hence there is a local minimum at $x = 0$.

There can even be a local minimum at $x = x_0$ where the function is differentiable at $x = x_0$ and $f'(x_0) \ne 0$. Consider the function $f(x) = x$ defined on the interval $[0,3]$. For this function, there is a global minimum at $x = 0$ even though $f'(0) = 1$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich - fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the fine print. "For a local minimum the first derivative has to be zero" isn't quite true. What's true is this:

*If* $f$ has a local minimum at $x$ and *if* $f$ is differentiable at $x$ *then* $f'(x)=0$.

The function $|x|$ obviously has a minimum at $x=0$; that does not contradict the above precisely because it's not differentiable there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 0 is a local minimum of that function, since there exists a $k > 0$ such that for all $\epsilon$ with $k > \epsilon > 0$ there is $f(x-\epsilon) > f(x)$ and $f(x+\epsilon) > f(x)$.

The function is indeed not differentiable at $x = 0$, however, this is not mandatory for an extremum.

Comment: ??? What does it mean for a function to be "contiguous"? (The function $|x|$ _is_ continuous at the origin...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes, I meant the derivative

Comment: You meant "$f'$ is not continuous at $0$, hence $f$ is not differentiable there"? That's not right - a function can be differentiable without the derivative being continuous."

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Hm, what is the value of f'(0) then?

Comment: Of course _this_ function is not differentiable at $0$. I didn't say otherwise. The fact that it's not differentiable does not _follow from_ the fact that $f'$ is not continuous at $0$, as you claimed.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I just can't think of a counterexample at the moment. Mind to show one up?

Comment: This is a standard example: Let $f(0)=0$ and for $x\ne0$ let $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x^{10})$. Then $f$ is differentiable everywhere, but $f'$ is not continuous at the origin.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Hm, isn't this merely an example for a continuous extension of f, so f' is indeed continuous at the origin, too?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "isn't this merely an example for a continuous extension of $f$". No, $f'$ is not continuous at the origin.

Comment: Ok, I understood the example now. Indeed, this fulfills what you said. So there is no easy connection between a differentiable function and its derivative, I will remove the (non-)causality in question.

Answer (score 0):

First, it is not "a local minima" because "minima" is plural.  You want "a local minim**um**", the singular.  That's trivial but it makes me wonder if you really understand what these words mean.  The **definitions** of "maximum" or "minimum" have nothing to do with a the derivative being $0$.  A particular $x= a$ gives a "local minimum" for $f$ is if $f(a)\le f(x) \ \forall x \in \mathcal{B}_\delta(a)$ where $\delta \rightarrow 0^+$.

(In mathematics, which has so many "formulas", there is a grave danger of confusing "learning mathematics" with "memorizing formulas".  Do not fall into that trap!  Understanding is better than memorizing.)